# Accepting track changes and cleaning up document for docx file

Tags: xml, asp.net-core, ms-word, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I store all of my files in onedrive and a few of my group members all making changes in tracked changes and comments. However, I am automating cleaning up these documents by accepting all changes and removing comments in my asp.net core application. First I create a stream and I download the file from onedrive via ms graph api. I do this as follows:

```
        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> FinalizeDraftQuestionSet([FromForm] string ID, [FromForm] int QuestionCount)
    {

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            var query = "exec A2P_Edit_0134_RR_FinalizeDocument_QA @ID, @UserID, @QuestionCount";
            var queryResult = connection.QuerySingle(query, new { ID = ID, UserID = UserID, QuestionCount = QuestionCount });

            if (queryResult.Count() != 0)
            {
                var filePathSource = Path.Combine(fileDirectory, queryResult.DOCUMENT_PATH_DRAFT);
                var filePathDestination = Path.Combine(fileDirectory, queryResult.DOCUMENT_PATH_FINAL);

                //pull question set template to memory stream to pass as parameter in the onedrive upload
                using (var memoryStream = await oneDrive.DriveItemDownloadAsync(SharedDriveID, filePathSource, "path"))
                {
                    AppTools appTools = new AppTools();
                    var acceptRevisions = appTools.AcceptRevisions(memoryStream);

                    var UploadResponse = await oneDrive.UploadFileStreamAsync(SharedDriveID, memoryStream, filePathDestination, "replace");

                    if (acceptRevisions = true)
                    {
                        return Ok(new { Result = "Success" });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Ok(new { Result = "Document Cleanup Failed" });
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return Ok(new { Result = "Document already exists" });
            }
        }
    }
```

This allows me to then use some of c# xml tools to load the word document in and run my additional code for cleaning up the document:

```
        public void DeleteComments(WordprocessingDocument document, string author = "")
    {
            
            // Set commentPart to the document WordprocessingCommentsPart, 
            // if it exists.
            WordprocessingCommentsPart commentPart =
                document.MainDocumentPart.WordprocessingCommentsPart;

            // If no WordprocessingCommentsPart exists, there can be no 
            // comments. Stop execution and return from the method.
            if (commentPart == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Create a list of comments by the specified author, or
            // if the author name is empty, all authors.
            List<Comment> commentsToDelete =
                commentPart.Comments.Elements<Comment>().ToList();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(author))
            {
                commentsToDelete = commentsToDelete.
                Where(c => c.Author == author).ToList();
            }
            IEnumerable<string> commentIds =
                commentsToDelete.Select(r => r.Id.Value);

            // Delete each comment in commentToDelete from the 
            // Comments collection.
            foreach (Comment c in commentsToDelete)
            {
                c.Remove();
            }

            // Save the comment part change.
            commentPart.Comments.Save();

            Document doc = document.MainDocumentPart.Document;

            // Delete CommentRangeStart for each
            // deleted comment in the main document.
            List<CommentRangeStart> commentRangeStartToDelete =
                doc.Descendants<CommentRangeStart>().
                Where(c => commentIds.Contains(c.Id.Value)).ToList();
            foreach (CommentRangeStart c in commentRangeStartToDelete)
            {
                c.Remove();
            }

            // Delete CommentRangeEnd for each deleted comment in the main document.
            List<CommentRangeEnd> commentRangeEndToDelete =
                doc.Descendants<CommentRangeEnd>().
                Where(c => commentIds.Contains(c.Id.Value)).ToList();
            foreach (CommentRangeEnd c in commentRangeEndToDelete)
            {
                c.Remove();
            }

            // Delete CommentReference for each deleted comment in the main document.
            List<CommentReference> commentRangeReferenceToDelete =
                doc.Descendants<CommentReference>().
                Where(c => commentIds.Contains(c.Id.Value)).ToList();
            foreach (CommentReference c in commentRangeReferenceToDelete)
            {
                c.Remove();
            }

            // Save changes back to the MainDocumentPart part.
            doc.Save();
    }

    public void RemoveTrackChanges(WordprocessingDocument wdDoc, string author = "")
    {
            Body body = wdDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

            // Handle the formatting changes.
            List<OpenXmlElement> changes =
                body.Descendants<ParagraphPropertiesChange>().Cast<OpenXmlElement>().ToList();

            foreach (OpenXmlElement change in changes)
            {
                change.Remove();
            }

            // Handle the deletions.
            List<OpenXmlElement> deletions =
                body.Descendants<Deleted>().Cast<OpenXmlElement>().ToList();

            deletions.AddRange(body.Descendants<DeletedRun>().Cast<OpenXmlElement>().ToList());

            deletions.AddRange(body.Descendants<DeletedMathControl>().Cast<OpenXmlElement>().ToList());

            foreach (OpenXmlElement deletion in deletions)
            {
                deletion.Remove();
            }

            // Handle the insertions.
            List<OpenXmlElement> insertions =
                body.Descendants<Inserted>().Cast<OpenXmlElement>().ToList();

            insertions.AddRange(body.Descendants<InsertedRun>().Cast<OpenXmlElement>().ToList());

            insertions.AddRange(body.Descendants<InsertedMathControl>().Cast<OpenXmlElement>().ToList());

            foreach (OpenXmlElement insertion in insertions)
            {
                // Found new content.
                // Promote them to the same level as node, and then delete the node.
                foreach (var run in insertion.Elements<Run>())
                {
                    if (run == insertion.FirstChild)
                    {
                        insertion.InsertAfterSelf(new Run(run.OuterXml));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        insertion.NextSibling().InsertAfterSelf(new Run(run.OuterXml));
                    }
                }
                insertion.RemoveAttribute("rsidR",
                    "https://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");
                insertion.RemoveAttribute("rsidRPr",
                    "https://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");
                insertion.Remove();
            }
    }

    public bool AcceptRevisions(MemoryStream memoryStream)
    {
        bool acceptedRevisions = false;
        using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(memoryStream, true))
        {
            try
            {
                DeleteComments(wordDoc);
                RemoveTrackChanges(wordDoc, "");
                acceptedRevisions = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                acceptedRevisions = false;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
        return acceptedRevisions;   
    }
```

Some users are using the online OneDrive editor for word and other users are using the open in desktop feature in OneDrive (we have office 365 installed on each desktop). When this code is run on the server you would think the track changes would be accepted and the comments deleted similar to if this was done manually in word by the user but instead only some track changes are accepted and things are moved around occasionally. and randomly placed and I still see some track change notes (ie, formatting change indicators like John Doe formatted Times New Romans 44 minutes ago). So maybe I am not accepting all changes or there is a bug in my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated because the point of this was to automate cleaning up the document but instead my users have to go back and manually clean this finalized document and triple check it didnt move things around.